# Umbraco 5 surface controller and partial macro

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco5

I'm playing with Umbraco 5 (complete newbie) and currently trying to experiment with the surface controller and macro's.

I've created a basic surface controller:

```
public class TestSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    //
    // GET: /TestSurface/

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetTest()
    {
        List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
        test.Add(new Test { TestTitle = "Test" });

        return View(test);
    }

}
```

And a partial macro:

```
@inherits PartialViewMacroPage
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Macros
@using Umbraco.Framework

@model IEnumerable<Umbraco.Models.Test>

<ul>
  @foreach (var test in Model)
  {
    <li>@test.TestTitle</li>
  }
</ul>
```

And on my home template, I call it:

```
@inherits RenderViewPage
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web;
@{
Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
 }

@section head
{
@Umbraco.RenderMacro("getTest")
}
```

How do I get it to just display test in the ul? I either get an error saying I can't use inherits if model is used, then if I take away inherits I get a message saying that the model supplied isn't as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@inherits RenderViewPage
Remove this line from your partial page, if you want i can post an example of a working surface controller action and partial view.
hope that helps.
Working Example is below,

```
public class MDSSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{        
    public MDSSurfaceController(IRoutableRequestContext routableRequestContext)
        : base(routableRequestContext)
    {
    }
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult ApartmentListMacro(string apartmentType, string Name, string PropertyRfDicItem, string RatesperNightDict, string SleepsDict, string BedroomsDict, string BathroomsDict, string ViewDict)
    {
        ApartmentListModel apM = new ApartmentListModel();
        //initialize model           
        return PartialView(apM);
    }
```

Then my Partial View is

```
@using Umbraco.Cms.Packages.SystemInfo.Models
@model Umbraco.Cms.Packages.SystemInfo.Models.ApartmentListModel
@{
//Html Code
}
```

Comment: If I take that away, I get an error stating that the view expected one model, but got something different.